# Mongo query to join elements of arrays contained in documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection that contains information about events and attendees. The documents in the collection look something like this

```
{event: event_1, attendees: [A, B, C]} // A, B and C attended at event_1 
{event: event_2, attendees: [A, B]}    // A and B attended at event_2
{event: event_3, attendees: [A]}       // A only attended at event_3
```

What I want to build is a query that allows me to know for each attendee how many events it attended as well as how many times he met the other attendees. In other words I would like to obtain something like this

```
{attendee: A, howManyEvents: 3, togetherWith: B, howManyTimes: 2}
{attendee: A, howManyEvents: 3, togetherWith: C, howManyTimes: 1}
{attendee: B, howManyEvents: 2, togetherWith: A, howManyTimes: 2}
{attendee: B, howManyEvents: 2, togetherWith: C, howManyTimes: 1}
{attendee: C, howManyEvents: 1, togetherWith: A, howManyTimes: 1}
{attendee: C, howManyEvents: 1, togetherWith: B, howManyTimes: 1}
```

Such list would allow me to know, for instance querying for `{attendee: B, togetherWith: A}`, that any time B goes to an event it also meets A (`howManyEvents` and `howManyTimes` are both 2). Similarly, 1/3 of the times A goes to an event there is also C.

Is there a way to build a query that returns a list like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query produce the results that you want.
To understand it, it can help to go stage by stage and see output.

Query

- map to add the together with field, with missing 1 member each time (the current member)
- unwind
- group by attendee to sum the distinct events => howManyTimes
- unwind
- group by attendee and sum togetherWith : 1 => togetherWith (total)

*if you see together with `NULL` its for events of 1 member, its important info if one attended was only in 1 event and alone

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251c7fff7e3c64c6511e179)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"a": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$attendees",
        "as": "a",
        "in": 
         {"attendee": "$$a",
          "event": "$event",
          "togetherWith": {"$setDifference": ["$attendees", ["$$a"]]}}}}}},
 {"$project": {"_id": 0, "a": 1}}, {"$unwind": "$a"},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$a"}},
 {"$unwind": 
   {"path": "$togetherWith", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
 {"$set": {"togetherWith": {"$ifNull": ["$togetherWith", null]}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": "$attendee",
    "howManyEvents": {"$addToSet": "$event"},
    "together": 
     {"$push": {"togetherWith": "$togetherWith", "howManyTimes": 1}}}},
 {"$set": {"attendee": "$_id", "_id": "$$REMOVE"}},
 {"$set": {"howManyEvents": {"$size": "$howManyEvents"}}},
 {"$unwind": "$together"},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$together", "$$ROOT"]}}},
 {"$project": {"together": 0}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": {"attendee": "$attendee", "togetherWith": "$togetherWith"},
    "howManyEvents": {"$first": "$howManyEvents"},
    "howManyTimes": {"$sum": "$howManyTimes"}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$_id", "$$ROOT"]}}},
 {"$project": {"_id": 0}}])
```

---

Query2 (alternative solution facet and more array operations)

- the first map is to add the `{:togetherWith ".." :howManyTimes 1}`
  to each attented
- 2 unwinds to get results like

  ```js
  {
  "attendee": "A",
  "togetherWith": "B",
  "howManyTimes": 1,
  "event": "event_1"
  },
  {
  "attendee": "A",
  "togetherWith": "C",
  "howManyTimes": 1,
  "event": "event_1"
  }
  ...
  ```
- 2 groups in a facet

  - count the distinct events(how many events)
  - sum the how many times (how many times)
- then its a map that combine the information from both those arrays
- 1 unwind of that array with all information
- simple tranformation

*If you see the results they contain also `"howManyTimes": 0` members, this happens when event had only 1 member, for A is not useful because we have the `howManyEvents` from other documents,
but for "Z" it is useful, so i kept those

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6251c862f7e3c64c6511e17a)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
   {"a": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$attendees",
        "as": "a",
        "in": 
         {"attendee": "$$a",
          "event": "$event",
          "togetherWith": 
           {"$filter": 
             {"input": 
               {"$map": 
                 {"input": "$attendees",
                  "as": "a1",
                  "in": 
                   {"$cond": 
                     [{"$ne": ["$$a", "$$a1"]},
                       {"togetherWith": "$$a1", "howManyTimes": 1}, null]}}},
              "as": "f",
              "cond": {"$ne": ["$$f", null]}}}}}}}},
 {"$project": {"_id": 0, "a": 1}}, {"$unwind": "$a"},
 {"$unwind": 
   {"path": "$a.togetherWith", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true}},
 {"$project": 
   {"attendee": "$a.attendee",
    "togetherWith": "$a.togetherWith.togetherWith",
    "howManyTimes": "$a.togetherWith.howManyTimes",
    "event": "$a.event"}},
 {"$facet": 
   {"a": 
     [{"$group": 
         {"_id": "$attendee", "howManyEvents": {"$addToSet": "$event"}}},
       {"$set": {"attendee": "$_id", "_id": "$$REMOVE"}},
       {"$set": {"howManyEvents": {"$size": "$howManyEvents"}}}],
    "b": 
     [{"$group": 
         {"_id": {"attendee": "$attendee", "togetherWith": "$togetherWith"},
          "howManyTimes": {"$sum": "$howManyTimes"}}},
       {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": {"$mergeObjects": ["$_id", "$$ROOT"]}}},
       {"$project": {"_id": 0}}]}},
 {"$set": 
   {"b": 
     {"$map": 
       {"input": "$b",
        "as": "m",
        "in": 
         {"$let": 
           {"vars": 
             {"howManyEvents": 
               {"$arrayElemAt": 
                 [{"$filter": 
                     {"input": "$a",
                      "as": "m1",
                      "cond": {"$eq": ["$$m.attendee", "$$m1.attendee"]}}},
                  0]}},
            "in": 
             {"$mergeObjects": 
               ["$$m",
                 {"howManyEvents": "$$howManyEvents.howManyEvents"}]}}}}}}},
 {"$unwind": "$b"}, {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$b"}},
 {"$match": {"$expr": {"$gt": ["$howManyTimes", 0]}}}])
```

Comment: Excellent, it works. Thanks. Well, actually it seems to work right with relatively small collections but it seems to not give me the expected results if the collection is big. I know that it sounds weird, but I am still investigating. It may well be that I am not doing the right checks. In any case, for small collection where I can easily anticipate the result, it works well.

Comment: i dont know, if you find a sample that doesn't work if you can send me to re-check it.
or if i have time i might re-check it with my sample data.

Comment: Your example works. I suspect I am making a mistake somewhere. I will keep you posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any straightway to do this, but you can try the aggregation pipeline as below,

- `$addFields` to add copy of `attendees` field
- `$unwind` deconstruct `attendees` array
- `$filter` to iterate loop of `togetherWith` and remove current `attendee` from copy field
- `$unwind` deconstruct `togetherWith` array
- `$group` by `attendee` and construct the array of `togetherWith` and count sum of `howManyEvents`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `togetherWith` array
- `$group` by `attendee` and `togetherWith` and get count of `howManyTimes`
- `$project` to format the result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: { togetherWith: "$attendees" } },
  { $unwind: "$attendees" },
  {
    $addFields: {
      togetherWith: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$togetherWith",
          cond: { $ne: ["$$this", "$attendees"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$togetherWith" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$attendees",
      togetherWith: { $push: "$togetherWith" },
      howManyEvents: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$togetherWith" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        attendee: "$_id",
        togetherWith: "$togetherWith"
      },
      howManyEvents: { $first: "$howManyEvents" },
      howManyTimes: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      attendee: "$_id.attendee",
      togetherWith: "$_id.togetherWith",
      howManyEvents: 1,
      howManyTimes: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BnLiod74FFF)